# Switch git provider in buildnumber-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jgit, buildnumber-maven-plugin

When using the `buildnumber-maven-plugin`, the execution fails when no git executable is in the `%PATH%` during a build on command line:

> ```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project test: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository :
> [ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command. Error while executing command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\dev\test"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
> ```

However, when executing the same build via eclipse `Run as -> Maven clean verify`, a commit id can be retrieved.

Since it works in eclipse, I tried to use the `maven-scm-provider-jgit` instead of `maven-scm-provider-gitexe` with `buildnumber-maven-plugin`, but apparently I did not configure it correctly.

This is the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**How can I switch to `maven-scm-provider-jgit`?**

Comment: What error/response did you get?

Comment: @centic The same as mentioned above Cannot run program "git" It looks like the maven-scm-provider-jgit is not used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `buildnumber-maven-plugin` needs to know, which git provider to use. The following configuration changes the git provider to `jgit`.

It is necessary to use at least version `1.9.5` of `maven-scm-provider-jgit`, since the InfoCommand is not implemented in `1.9.4`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <providerImplementations>
            <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```